# Where is the Eschewmenical blog?

Tags: support, feature-request

Question says it all, really. I would like to read/revisit the blog. How do I find it?

When there is a new post, it appears in the Community Bulletin panel on the right. Nothing there at the moment.

[image: Bulletin panel]

There's nothing in the top menu:

[image: Top menu]

And the "blog" link at the bottom is part of the general Stack links:

[image: Bottom menu]

If I don't know the site blog's url, how do I find it (apart from Google, where it's currently the top result)? Should it not be linked on the site rather more permanently than it appears to be?

*Side issue: Now that I have found it via Google, it appears still to be in beta livery.*

Comment: I suppose I should comment (for future users finding this question) that it's at http://christianity.blogoverflow.com/‎

Comment: yeah we'd have to snag Jin to get us a blog theme and considering it's not currently active I'm not sure it would rate at this time.

Comment: @wax Yes, the theme was only an observation in passing. But it would nice to be able to find it from C.SE.

Comment: Whenever we've got a new blog post it goes in the community events thing.  It used to go in the top right menu for a couple of days, I liked that.

Comment: FYI: I've unfrozen the [Eschewmenical blog chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2567/eschewmenical-blog-room).  I think it would be good to have new content before we do much more to publicize the blog.  I mean, there's great content over there (if I _do_ say so myself), but no _fresh_ content.